# How to create a side menu with php and add it to all Views? The views do not stay in the side menu, they scroll down

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysql

I am learning MySQL and for this I am creating a simple inventory system.
I've created a side menu that also has a top navigation bar, from a simple template created with just html, bootstrap.

From this menu, we will have access to all the content of the application: Users, Products, Categories, etc...

I want this side menu to be displayed in all views or pages that are added to the application in the future, that is, all views must have this side menu (Sidebar) and the navigation bar (NavBar)

Each view is created independently, for now the application only has 3 views: home, login and 404

The teacher has created a system to call the different views from the index.php, since the application will have a login as follows:

```
<?php require "./inc/sesionStart.php" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <?php include "./inc/headsidebar.php" ?>
  <title>Administrador de inventario</title>
</head>
<body>
  <?php
  if (!isset($_GET['vista']) || $_GET['vista'] == "") {
    $_GET['vista'] = "login";
  }

  if (is_file("./vistas/" . $_GET['vista'] . ".php") && $_GET['vista'] != "login" && $_GET['vista'] != "404") {
    include "./inc/sidebar.php";
    include "./vistas/" . $_GET['vista'] . ".php";
  } else {

    if ($_GET['vista'] == "login") {
      include "./vistas/login.php";
    } else {
      include "./vistas/404.php";
    }
  }

  ?>
</body>
</html>
```

The Login and 404 Views work perfectly, since these pages should not have the side menu (Sidebar) and the Navigation Bar (NavBar)
The problem arises when I have added a new View (HOME), this view needs to have the Side Menu and the Navigation Bar.

However, when I add the URL to the browser: http://localhost:8888/index.php?vista=home , it shows what you see in the screenshot below, the interface created for the HOME View, it shows after of the Sidebar view, that is, we must scroll to be able to see the content of HOME.

Actually, HOME and all views (except Login and 404) must have the SIDEBAR and the NAVBAR

[image: home view image]

And this is what is displayed when I want to enter HOME:

[image: image when I want to go Home]

How can I correct this?
What do I have to do so that all the views that I create in the future have a Side Menu and a Navigation Bar?

I am really following the course and trying to learn with the structure system that the tutorial shows, I do not have the knowledge to make my corrections.
This is the file system I have in the project:

[image: app file system]

I show the file with which the Side Menu and the NavBar are created and the HOME view file with its corresponding css.

If you don't understand the code, [I've created a repository on GitHub](https://github.com/dianacuentagithub/inventario) to record the changes I make to the project:

https://github.com/dianacuentagithub/inventario

I don't want to continue with the tutorial until I get this corrected, I hope to find an idea or advice to learn how to avoid this.

I hope to see explained well what I need for the application, it is difficult to use the translator
Thank you

**sidebar.php**

```
<head>
  <?php include "./inc/headsidebar.php" ?>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <nav id="sidebar">
      <div class="sidebar-header">
        <img src="./img/gato-2.png" class="rounded-circle" alt="logo">
        <h3 class="tituloPanel"> Panel Administrador </h3>
        <strong>PA</strong>
      </div>
      <ul class="list-unstyled components">
        <li class="usuarioColor active ">
          <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="sidebaruser dropdown-toggle">
            <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
            Usuarios
          </a>
          <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
            <li>
              <a href="#">Nuevo</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#"> Lista</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Buscar</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="categoriasColor">
          <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">
            <i class="fas fa-copy"></i>
            Categorias
          </a>
          <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
            <li>
              <a href="#">Nuevo </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Buscar</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="productosColor">
          <a href="#pageProductos" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">
            <i class="fas fa-cubes"></i>
            Productos
          </a>
          <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageProductos">
            <a href="#">Nuevo </a>
            <a href="#">Lista</a>
            <a href="#">Por Categoria</a>
            <a href="#">Buscar</a>
          </ul>
        </li>
    </nav>
    <div id="content">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info">
            <i class="fas fa-align-justify"></i>
            <span></span>
          </button>
          <button class="btn btn-dark d-inline-block d-lg-none ml-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <i class="fas fa-align-justify"></i>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">Mi Cuenta</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Salir</button>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php include "inc/script.php"; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

**home.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/homeStyle.css">
  <title>home</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" id="jimena">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9" id="texto">
            <h1 class="text-center hi">Hello...
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/homeStyle.css">
            </h1>
            <div class="div-center underline">
            </div>
            <p class="text-center intro">  This is the view of HOME</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**headsidebar.php**

```
<title>Menu Lateral</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/sidebarStyle.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css">
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/solid.js" integrity="sha384-tzzSw1/Vo+0N5UhStP3bvwWPq+uvzCMfrN1fEFe+xBmv1C/AtVX5K0uZtmcHitFZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/fontawesome.js" integrity="sha384-6OIrr52G08NpOFSZdxxz1xdNSndlD4vdcf/q2myIUVO0VsqaGHJsB0RaBE01VTOY" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**script.php**

```
 <!-- jQuery CDN - Slim version (=without AJAX) -->
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <!-- Popper.JS -->
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function() {
       $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
     });
   });
 </script>

 <script src="./js/ajax.js"></script>
```

I have searched the internet for examples similar to what I need for my project and studied their code, but my limited experience in the php language prevents me from correcting it by myself, so I have come to this place in search of advice

Comment: In my opinion, your problem is not related to PHP. Just HTML and CSS.

Comment: The problem is I'm a php student, I understand html, but I don't know how to link my Sidebar to the different pages.
Everything accumulates a little and I mess up by myself

Answer (score 0):

Your sidebar.php is defining the `<body>` tag which is conflicting with the `<body>` tag in home.php

Remove the `<head>` and `<body>` tags from sidebar.php

Once you do that your layout should work correctly.

Heres how youre files should look:

**home.php**

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/homeStyle.css">
  <div class="container-fluid h-100">
    <div class="row h-100">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 h-100" id="jimena">
        <div class="row h-100">
          <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9 h-100" id="texto">
            <h1 class="text-center hi">Hello...
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/homeStyle.css">
            </h1>
            <div class="div-center underline">
            </div>
            <p class="text-center intro">  This is the view of HOME</p>
            <!--<p class="text-center nombre"> Miguel Espeso </p>-->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**sidebar.php**

```
    <!-- Sidebar  -->
    <nav id="sidebar">
      <div class="sidebar-header">
        <img src="./img/gato-2.png" class="rounded-circle" alt="logo">
        <h3 class="tituloPanel"> Panel Administrador </h3>
        <strong>PA</strong>
      </div>
      <ul class="list-unstyled components">
        <li class="usuarioColor active ">
          <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="sidebaruser dropdown-toggle">
            <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
            Usuarios
          </a>
          
          <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
            <li>
              <a href="#">Nuevo</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#"> Lista</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Buscar</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="categoriasColor">
          <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">
            <i class="fas fa-copy"></i>
            Categorias
          </a>
          <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
            <li>
              <a href="#">Nuevo </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Lista</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Buscar</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="productosColor">
          <a href="#pageProductos" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">
            <i class="fas fa-cubes"></i>
            Productos
          </a>
          <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageProductos">
            <a href="#">Nuevo </a>
            <a href="#">Lista</a>
            <a href="#">Por Categoria</a>
            <a href="#">Buscar</a>
          </ul>
        </li>

       <!--  <li>
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fas fa-briefcase"></i>
            Detalles
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="alertasColor">
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fas fa-image"></i>
            Alertas
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fas fa-question"></i>
            FAQ
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i>
            Contacto
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="list-unstyled CTAs">
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="download">Muestra</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="article">Muestras</a>
        </li>
      </ul> -->
    </nav>

    <!-- Nav Bar  -->
  
  <?php include "inc/script.php"; ?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php require "./inc/sesionStart.php" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <?php include "./inc/headsidebar.php" ?>

  <title>Administrador de inventario</title>
</head>

<body>
  <?php


  if (!isset($_GET['vista']) || $_GET['vista'] == "") {
    $_GET['vista'] = "login";
  }

  if (is_file("./vistas/" . $_GET['vista'] . ".php") && $_GET['vista'] != "login" && $_GET['vista'] != "404") {
    #include "./inc/navbar.php";
    ?>
    <div class="row h-100" style="margin:0 !important">
      <div class="col-auto h-100" style="padding: 0px !important; margin: 0px !important;">
        <?php include "./inc/sidebar.php";?>
      </div>
      <div class="col h-100" style="padding: 0px !important; margin: 0px !important;">
        <?php include "./vistas/" . $_GET['vista'] . ".php";?>
      </div>
    </div> 
    <?php
    
    
    #include "./inc/script.php";
  } else {

    if ($_GET['vista'] == "login") {
      include "./vistas/login.php";
    } else {
      include "./vistas/404.php";
    }
  }

  ?>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I have already made the changes you suggested, but everything is still the same, you can see the screenshot [here](https://ibb.co/LR4BdkR).  Also remove <body> and <head> from home view

Comment: Ah... looking at your repo https://github.com/dianacuentagithub/inventario/blob/main/index.php the index.php file is already defining the <head> and <body> tags... that means anything that gets included into the index.php should not have <head> or <body> tags

Comment: What does this mean ? I already removed those tags from the home.php view. I don't know what else I can do, I am a girl with little experience and I am trying to learn little by little, what can I do to correct it? In `html`, it would suffice to add the Sidebar in all the new pages, but in the tutorial. use that structure

Comment: also.. in your sidebar.php and your home.php you are wrapping both in a <div class="wrapper"> tag. That tag will cause the sidebar to take up the full width as well as the home.php content. The <div class="wrapper"> tag should be in your index.php file

Comment: And what would be the way to place it in the index.php, where exactly? Can you show an example ?

Comment: I edited my response and gave you the exact code for the 3 files that needed to be fixed from your repo

Comment: I really appreciate what you are doing, it is guiding me to get what I need. And I feel embarrassed about this, considering that you are going out of your way to help me. But we still have two problems: Visually it is very bad, it is disproportionate; and the navigation bar is missing, it is important because from there it will be the access to the user profile. [You can see the result in the screenshot](https://ibb.co/JKkrmv4). I am sorry that it happens with the time you are dedicating to help me

Comment: I would be very grateful to solve this, but Of course I understand if you don't continue to show me your support and dedicate your time to me. Maybe I should create another file with "The Navigation Bar". You have given me good ideas, but it will take me time to try to solve it with the changes you have shown me

Comment: You will need to play with the css height properties... I cant in good conscience do your homework for you. I suggest looking up "css flex box height" on google and learning how to work with the css